# No puedo acceder a un elemento con un ID que contiene % con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un elemento input de forma dinámica para introducir un título a una imagen que sube el usuario.

Cuando creo el elemento le asigno como id title + el nombre de la imagen subida. Para quitar los espacios y las tildes que pueda tener el nombre de la imagen que se esta subiendo añado un encodeURI(nombreImagen). Esto me devuelve una cadena con `%`

Ejemplo: "jardín juegos" --> encodeURI devuelve `jardi%CC%81n%20juegos`

El elemento input se crea y se muestra en la página correctamente con ese id.

El problema es cuando intento acceder a él cuando salvan los datos. Accedo a él mediante `$("#titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos").val()` para coger su valor. Para los elementos que se crean sin `%` porque no tengan espacios o acentos me va bien. ¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor del elemento?

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Al final he usado document.getElementById("titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos").value y me devuelve el valor sin error. Uso ese id porque es el que se almacena en la base de datos, el nombre con el que se guarda en la carpeta de subida, el id de la imagen que se muestra y el id del boton de borrar

Comment: Maria Jo, con `getElementById` te funciona por lo que dice Blonfu en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86958/15855). Considera marcarla como aceptada. . Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dice @blonfu en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86958/6491), jQuery usa CSS Sintaxis para seleccionar los elementos.

Para tratar estos caracteres como la notación CSS, deberían ser escapados mediante la colocación de dos barras invertidas delante de ellos.

```js
$('#titlejardi\\%CC\\%81n\\%20juegos').css( 'color', 'red' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos">
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet
</div>
```

o con regex:

```js
function jq( myid ) {
 
  return "#" + myid.replace( /[:.[\],=@%]/g, "\\$&" );
 
}

$( jq('titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos') ).css( 'color', 'green' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos">
      Lorem ipsum dolor amet
    </div>
```

Fuente: [learn.jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Comment: @Mariano - Por el bien de tus ojos.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

En principio en HTML no hay problema con usar esos caracteres en los id, tampoco en javascript.

Ejemplo:

```js
var contenido = document.getElementById("titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos").innerHTML;
console.log("Texto del div: " + contenido);
```

```html
<div id="titlejardi%CC%81n%20juegos">
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet
</div>
```

Sin embargo en CSS no se pueden usar ciertos caracteres, creo que solo se pueden usar letras, números, guiones y guiones bajos. Tampoco puede empezar por un número.

jQuery utiliza selectores CSS para acceder a los elementos y posiblemente por eso no funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Yo no usaría como `id` ese tipo de estructura. En todo caso podrías hacer uso de alguna librería o función a medida que devolviera un texto más apropiado para un id. Si buscas información del tipo "normalize name javascript" encontrarás enlaces interesantes y funciones de la librería básica que puedes usar como [String.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

La otra opción es que uses otro elemento que no sea el id para hacer la seleccion por ejemplo [data-imagename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector) o lo que sea.

Comment: Francisco, esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Intenta ejemplificar y dar solucion a su problema